# Allow customers to buy out-of-stock items in OpenCart

Tags: php, module, opencart

I have been looking for a module to allow a client to be able to still purchase an item if the stock level is 0. Is this feature available in OpenCart 1.5.x?

I have set the product to 2-3 days, however on the site front-end it still shows the product as out of stock. Is there away to alert the client of the 2-3 day delay, and still allow the client to purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the function that prevents an out of stock item from going to checkout. Go to catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php and change

```
public function index() {
    // Validate cart has products and has stock.
    if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
}
```

to

```
public function index() {
    // Validate cart has products and has stock.
    if (!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
}
```

I don't remember if it blocks you from adding it to the cart in the first place so let me know. Good luck David!

**Update**

**To change "Out of Stock" on the product page**, I have changed it myself with the settings in the store so if that isn't working for you then you can go into catalog/controller/product/product.php and where you see

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
        }
```

Change to:

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $this->data['stock'] = "2-3 Days";
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
        }
```

Change the text within those brackets to whichever phrase works for you.

Comment: Thanks Cleverbot. Really Appreciate you taking the time to help me. I will try this code out and post back! Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Hi CleverBot. Just tried your code, however it seem that the i cant add the items to my cart as handler for "add to cart" just shows "out of Stock"

Comment: @DavidMurray Hey I don't have any test stores running to see for myself. Does it let you add it to cart from the product page? Or is the problem that it lets you add it but still says "Out of Stock"

Comment: It wont allow me to even add to cart. i I will PM you my site address if you want to test.

Comment: Sure. add me on skype as theres no pm on stack david (at)davincidesign dot co dot za

Comment: It's worth mentioning (although obvious to some) that in the Opencart Dashboard you must also change Settings > Options > Stock. "Stock Checkout" will need to be set to "Yes" and "Show Out Of Stock Warning" set to "No" otherwise the cart page will show a message warning the customer that there is insufficient stock.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature built into OpenCart as standard. The setting should be on the "Option" tab in your settings page

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay, I have however tried this but the shop front just shows "Out Of Stock". However in the availability tab it shows 2-3 days.

Comment: I see. The answer was in response to the first part of your question. If you just need to hide the stock status, you can do so by removing it from your product.tpl file

Answer (score -1):

First find

```
if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
```

and replace with

```
if (1==1 || !$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
```

Comment: Why would you even need the `if`-clause in this case? It's a tautalogy.